# Determining the correct Null hypothesis

Tags: probability, statistics

The data contain the results of the drug which lowers the Cholesterol level. Patients were split in two groups. The first one was administered drug and the other one placebo. Use appropriate statistical tool to determine whether the drug is effective.

Would it be corrected to say that the Null Hypothesis is :

**Null Hypothesis- There is no significant difference in lowered Cholesterol Level between patients given the drug and the other one placebo.**

Comment: I'd say that's basically right.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: in this type of studies, you have both basal and follow-up cholesterol levels. To demonstrate the effectiveness of therapy,  you have to focus on the changes between basal levels and follow-up levels.